# How write a typescript generics type for Array one-to-one conversion to Object

Tags: typescript

### Target

I want write a typescript generics type for Array one-to-one conversion to Object,
the function like

```js
transArrayToObject([
  [1, 'A'],
  [2, 'B'],
] as const)

// type output
{
  readonly A: 1;
  readonly B: 2;
}
```

### I’ve tried

```js
type Data = readonly (readonly [number, string])[]

type TransArrayToObject = <TD extends Data>(
  data: TD,
) => {
  readonly [K in TD[number][1]]: TD[number][0]
}

// Code details are omitted
const transArrayToObject = (() => ({})) as TransArrayToObject

transArrayToObject([
  [1, 'A'],
  [2, 'B'],
] as const)
```

but the type result is:

```js
{
  readonly A: 1 | 2;
  readonly B: 1 | 2;
}
```

This is not what i want. I don't know how write 'A' corresponds to 1，'B' corresponds to 2，

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this example:

```js
const Tpl = [
  [1, 'A'],
  [2, 'B'],
] as const

type Tpl = typeof Tpl


type Transform<
  Tuple extends readonly any[],
  Result extends Readonly<Record<string, any>> = {}> =
  (Tuple extends []
    ? Result // last call
    : Tuple extends readonly [infer Head, ... infer Tail]
    ? (Head extends readonly [infer Value, infer Key]
      ? (Key extends PropertyKey
        ? Transform<Tail, Result & Readonly<Record<Key, Value>>>
        : never)
      : never)
    : never)

type Result = Transform<Tpl>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAKgBwDYwLwwNoCgaYIwA0MA5AILEC6BOmATEcQEKXUUwCGEMokUWWUAJ4IApvGRoYQ0SABm4pPwHCxcAE7tIskGoC2AHhpwArsjEiAHlBFgAJlzUj2t8EkEcwgjFRoAlERDGSLCW1nZc-s6ugvr%20oGq2%20tBqAJZgAOZEmoIAfDmSAN4AvvmoNAAUJmYwoTb2mBQ0uAD8MP6BwU0wAFzwpkjmVnUOTi5gbphpsiJqMAASo0QAdCswUzPw7ClIjbgtMOULzjVD4TCOUePuGOuzAGrsSMYiRLcwANIigrt7%20%20Wf7lqZwACmoQKI1EIAV1fq11JoINo9Po4FskER2kFYAAyNqjaKxETxRIAogPJ4iPI5GF7XpgEQANxmAEoaXTGSyuuymWpWcpRHiOrB0PCtDoDIgkNSgA)

**`Transform`** - iterates through `Tpl` and infers each element. If element is a tuple with key/value pair, it creates a `Record<Key,Value>` , assigns it to `Result` and calls `Transform` recursively again

If you are interested in tuple manipulations, check my [blog](https://catchts.com/tuples)

Comment: I get it, this example has benefited me a lot, thank you very much!

Comment: @SimonWong if you are interested in tuple manipulations, you can check my blog https://catchts.com/tuples